# how can I assign the list with zeroes when number of elements is unknown to me

Tags: python, list

I want to store the number of copies of different books in a list as
`[10,14,12,16,42,23]`. Here the first element i.e.of `index[0]` represents first book has 10 copies, second book `(index[1])` has 14 copies like this. But the problem is that I don't know how many kind of books exists, i.e. total number of elements of list is unknown. so that i created an empty list as below:

```
li = []
```

After that I run a for loop and in each iteration I want to add and update the list element as follows:

```
for x in range(5):
    li[x] = li[x] + 1
```

But I am getting the following error:
`li[x] = li[x] + 1
IndexError: list index out of range`
Because `li[x]` has not been assigned to `0` or any value. My question is how can I assign the list with zeroes when number of elements is unknown to me and I am appending the list elements dynamically. Please suggest some approach to achieve my requirement.

Comment: Use a `collections.Counter`/`collections.defaultdict(int)` object, you should be able to automatically increment as you are trying to do.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thank you for the solution. It works perfectly for me. I have used collections.Counter.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign 0 as a value in the list.
You can try :

```
>>> for x in range(5):
      li.append(0)

>>> print li
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

>>> for x in range(5):
      li[x] = li[x] + 1 

>>> print li
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Actually I am working with large number of elements. So in that case running the loop twice seems inefficient. But thanks for the solution.

Comment: @harsha collection counter would be a correct solution for this scenario. still an upvote for understanding the OP

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
> li = [0] * 5
```

This is how `li` will look like :

```
> li =  [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Since you don't know the size so all you can do is to create a list

```
> li = []
```

and after some condition keep appending `zero` to it

```
> if condition: 
     li.append(0)
```

Comment: I already mentioned that number of elements is unknown before for loop.